# Error in FUN(X[[i]],...) : object 'yearID' not found

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

Here's my code:
[This is the image of my data where you can see what the column titles are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCuWv.png)
here's the copy of my salary data:

```
dput(salary_data[1:5, ])
structure(list(yearID = c(1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L), 
teamID = c("ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL", "ATL"), lgID = c("NL", 
"NL", "NL", "NL", "NL"), playerID = c("barkele01", "bedrost01", 
"benedbr01", "campri01", "ceronri01"), salary = c(870000L, 
550000L, 545000L, 633333L, 625000L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

and the copy of my pitching data:

```
dput(pitching_data[1:5, ])
structure(list(playerID = c("bechtge01", "brainas01", "fergubo01", 
"fishech01", "fleetfr01"), yearID = c(1871L, 1871L, 1871L, 1871L, 
1871L), stint = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), teamID = c("PH1", "WS3", 
"NY2", "RC1", "NY2"), lgID = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), W = c(1L, 12L, 
0L, 4L, 0L), L = c(2L, 15L, 0L, 16L, 1L), G = c(3L, 30L, 1L, 
24L, 1L), GS = c(3L, 30L, 0L, 24L, 1L), CG = c(2L, 30L, 0L, 22L, 
1L), SHO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), SV = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
IPouts = c(78L, 792L, 3L, 639L, 27L), H = c(43L, 361L, 8L, 
295L, 20L), ER = c(23L, 132L, 3L, 103L, 10L), HR = c(0L, 
4L, 0L, 3L, 0L), BB = c(11L, 37L, 0L, 31L, 3L), SO = c(1L, 
13L, 0L, 15L, 0L), BAOpp = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), ERA = c(7.96, 4.5, 27, 4.35, 10), IBB = 
c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), WP = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), HBP = 
c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), BK = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BFP = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), GF = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), R = c(42L, 292L, 
9L, 257L, 21L), SH =c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), SF = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), GIDP = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)

player_data <- read.csv("Master.csv")
pitching_data <- read.csv("Pitching.csv")
salary_data <- read.csv("Salaries.csv")
inflation_index <- read.csv("inflation.csv")


salary_data$yearID <- as.factor(salary_data$yearID)

ggplot(salary_data)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=yearID, y=salary)) 

summary_salary <- summarize(group_by(salary_data, yearID),
                        Q1 = quantile(salary,.25,na.rm=T),
                        median=median(salary,na.rm=T), 
                        Q3 = quantile(salary,.75,na.rm=T), 
                        min=min(salary,na.rm=T), 
                        max=max(salary,na.rm=T))
summary_salary$yearID <- 
    as.numeric(as.character(summary_salary$yearID))
ggplot(summary_salary)+
  geom_line(aes(x=yearID, y=median))

ggplot(pitching_data)+ 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=yearID, y=ERA))
    pitching_data$yearID <- as.factor(pitching_data$yearID)

ggplot(pitching_data)+
  geom_line(aes(x=yearID, y=median))

pitching_data <- summarize(group_by(pitching_data, ERA),
                       median=median(ERA,na.rm=T))
```

So I'm getting a couple of errors in this code. First of all, I'm confused because the data I have has a column titled "yearID" in it. In the boxplot line, there's no issue graphing the yearID, but in the geom_line one it says yearID can't be found. I'm also wondering if my next line of code, if that is the correct way to take the median of the ERA. ERA is another column in my data.

The other error I'm getting is after running the boxplot code. It's telling me "Warning message:
Removed 90 rows containing
non-finite values
(stat_boxplot)"

so I'm not really sure how to fix that.

Comment: Instead of sharing a picture of your data in a spreadsheet program, please share copy/pasteable text of what your data is in R. `dput()` is a command that makes a copy/pasteable version of data, including all class and structure information. Please share `dput(salary_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows. (Or maybe `summary_salary`... wherever your problem starts)

Comment: I'm also curious why you keep converting `yearID` from `factor` to `numeric` and back. It looks like it imports as `numeric`, you then convert it to `factor`, then in `salary_summary` you go back to `numeric`, but in `pitching_data` you go to `factor`...

Comment: I added the copies of my data. As for changing it from a factor to numeric, this is for a class assignment so I was just following the protocol. I believe the first two times were because it told me to do that, and the third time it gave me an error so I switched it back again